# Kotlin/Native How to use a header-only C/C++ library

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

So I'm trying to use stb_image in my Kotlin/Native project and I am having trouble trying to include it in my project. It's a header only library and konan seems to expect a compiled object file anyways so I was wondering if there is any way of just generating the cstubs and then using the header for linking unless I have to compile a basic translation file since stb_image only requires you to have a translation unit that defines `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` however I have that defined in my compilerOpts `-GSTB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION`. Would it be easier to just compile a translation unit, create the static object, and then link against it or does K/N have some way of doing that for me?

I am using Gradle Multiplatform so if there is some gradle script I can run then please let me know.

Comment: Do you have a source code example for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My `-GSTB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` is supposed to be `-DSTB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` and I needed to put my `-I` switch in my `compilerOpts` not `linkerOpts`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend actually creating a translation file but it's not required.
You can just give the header file with the compileropts as you've done and that should work.

You can look at [this](https://github.com/Dominaezzz/kgl/commit/5cd996ba8000225f69dc869a5fc77707b2dc695c) as a reference. I'm working on a wrapper in my free time.

Comment: Thanks but I ended up finding out that my ``-GSTB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENETATION`` was supposed to be ``-DSTB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION`` alongside the fact my ``-I`` switch was being passed to linkerOpts not compilerOpts. Thanks!